# React JS How to Set State in One Component from Another Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constructor, callback

**This is absolutely not a duplicate.**

1. This question is a React question.  The question that this is supposedly a duplicate of is straight JavaScript.
2. The problem was how i sent in my React function and not how i was referencing this or anything specific to "this".
3. This is actually very helpful as it shows how to update state in REACT!!! from one component to another which allows for more functional components which is a great thing for efficiency in REACT!!!!

So unfair.

**This is absolutely not a duplicate.**

**Please remove the duplicate marking!**

**Here is the original question...**

i have a couple of questions about some code i inherited.  i work on an intranet so i have to type a sample of what i am asking about.

**first question**, i have a "class" like the following, is it a JS class or a React class?  i assume React...

```
import React from 'react';

class SomeUtil {
  constructor() {
    this.doAbc = this.doAbc.bind(this)
  }

  doAbc(...){
    ...
  }
}
export default SomeUtil;
```

i noticed there is no super() - should i add that?

**second question** has to do with creating a similar class but i can't get it to work as i want.

```
import React from 'react';

class SomeOtherUtil {
  constructor(someCallback) {

    this.externalCallback = someCallback

    this.doXyz = this.doXyz.bind(this)
    this.doXxz = this.doXxz.bind(this)
    **//do i need to bind externalCallback here ?**
  }

  doXyz(...){
    this.externalCallback('hello world!')
  }

  doXxz(...){
    this.externalCallback('hello bob!')
  }
}
export default SomeOtherUtil;
```

now, when i use SomeOtherUtil i want to use it like this...

```
//inside a React Component
someRandomReactComponentMethod() {
  let myUtil = new SomeOtherUtil(this.someRandomCallback)
  myUtil.doXyz();
  myUtil.doXxz();
}
```

---

### UPDATE

i figured out my problem.  i was trying to do this...

```
//inside a React Component
someRandomReactComponentMethod() {
  let myUtil = new DataUtil(this.setState)
  myUtil.getThenSetData(...);
  myUtil.getAnotherWayAndSetData(...);
}
```

and i had to do this instead ...

```
//inside a React Component
someRandomReactComponentMethod() {
  let myUtil = new DataUtil((data)=>this.setState(data))
  myUtil.getThenSetData();
  myUtil.getAnotherWayAndSetData();
}
```

i'm still not convinced this is a duplicate of the question mentioned above but whatever.

Thanks for answering the first question about JS class vs React class.  Wish i could give half a vote. :)  i wasn't sure about my first question becausee react was imported at the top that it would get compiled into a react class or straight JS.  Now i know.  Also, in the past when i worked with JS objects i had to use prototype to make a new instance.  So it was confusing to me.

Comment: Unless your class `extends React.Component` then it does not have access to the React factory.

Comment: Regarding your first question, you don't need to (and cannot) use `super` if you don't `extend` another class

Comment: i don't agree that this question is a duplicate.  the question you refer to states about accessing this in a callback.  i'm asking how to pass a callback to a class so that all its functions can access the callback.

Answer (score 1):

> first question, i have a "class" like the following, is it a JS class or a React class? i assume React...

React Components are JavaScript classes that extend `React.Component`. This example does not: it's just a class, and doesn't look like it implements the component interface.

> //do i need to bind externalCallback here ?**

It depends on how it's called. If you are, for instance, responding to a `click` handler, you'll want to bind it so that the `this` value for the handler refers to the component rather than the clicked element.

Comment: i showed how it is called.  it is called in the doXyz() and doXxz()

Comment: In that case, no, you don't have to bind doXyz. But if you end up calling it in a different way, you'll need to bind it.

Answer (score 0):

first: no, you class does not extend any class, so you do not have to call `super`. I think you're confusing something like

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    ...
  }
}
```

second, depends what you want the `this` context to be - if you want it to be `SomeOtherUtil` then yes, you need to bind it... but you probably don't.